# How to create n-dimensional sparse tensor? (pytorch)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I want to initialize tensor to sparse tensor.
When tensor's dimensional is 2, I can use `torch.nn.init.sparse(tensor, sparsity=0.1)`

```
import torch
dim = torch.Size([3,2])
w = torch.Tensor(dim)
torch.nn.init.sparse_(w, sparsity=0.1)
```

Result

```
tensor([[ 0.0000,  0.0147],
        [-0.0190,  0.0004],
        [-0.0004,  0.0000]])
```

But when tensor dimensions > 2, this function isn't work.

```
v = torch.Tensor(torch.Size([5,5,30,2]))
torch.nn.init.sparse_(v, sparsity=0.1)
```

Result

```
ValueError: Only tensors with 2 dimensions are supported
```

I need this because I want to use it to initialize the convolution weights.

`torch.nn.init.sparse_()` function's def is below

```
def sparse_(tensor, sparsity, std=0.01):
    r"""Fills the 2D input `Tensor` as a sparse matrix, where the
    non-zero elements will be drawn from the normal distribution
    :math:`\mathcal{N}(0, 0.01)`, as described in `Deep learning via
    Hessian-free optimization` - Martens, J. (2010).

    Args:
        tensor: an n-dimensional `torch.Tensor`
        sparsity: The fraction of elements in each column to be set to zero
        std: the standard deviation of the normal distribution used to generate
            the non-zero values

    Examples:
        >>> w = torch.empty(3, 5)
        >>> nn.init.sparse_(w, sparsity=0.1)
    """
    if tensor.ndimension() != 2:
        raise ValueError("Only tensors with 2 dimensions are supported")

    rows, cols = tensor.shape
    num_zeros = int(math.ceil(sparsity * rows))

    with torch.no_grad():
        tensor.normal_(0, std)
        for col_idx in range(cols):
            row_indices = torch.randperm(rows)
            zero_indices = row_indices[:num_zeros]
            tensor[zero_indices, col_idx] = 0
    return tensor
```

How could I make n-dimensional sparse tensor?

Is there a way in pytorch to create this kind of tensor?

Or can I make it another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is an implementation of the following method:

> The best random initialization scheme we found was one of our own design, "sparse initialization". In this scheme we hard limit the
> number of non-zero incoming connection weights to each
> unit (we used 15 in our experiments) and set the biases to
> 0 (or 0.5 for tanh units).

- Deep learning via Hessian-free optimization - Martens, J. (2010).

The reason it is not supported for higher order tensors is because it maintains the same proportion of zeros in each column, and it is not clear which [subset of] dimensions this condition should be maintained across for higher order tensors.

You can implement this initialization strategy with [dropout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67282712/randomly-set-some-elements-in-a-tensor-to-zero-with-low-computational-time/67283352#67283352) or an equivalent function e.g:

```py
def sparse_(tensor, sparsity, std=0.01):
    with torch.no_grad():
        tensor.normal_(0, std)
        tensor = F.dropout(tensor, sparsity)
    return tensor
```

If you wish to enforce column, channel, etc-wise proportions of zeros (as opposed to just total proportion) you can implement logic similar to the original function.